# How to read particular text lines with python?

Tags: python

I want to read particular lines from the text file. E.g. all the contents between "This contents information"

[image]

I have created a script to perform the task, but it's not a good method. Are there any better way to do it?

```
readText=open("test.txt","r")

wanted_lines = [4,5,6,7]
count = 1
with open('test.txt', 'r') as infile:
     for line in infile:
          line = line.strip()
          if count in wanted_lines:
               print(line)
          else:
               pass
          count += 1
```

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 3):

You can compare each line to the sentinel, start outputting once it matches, and stop outputting once it matches again:

```
with open('test.txt') as infile:
    for output in False, True:
        for line in map(str.rstrip, infile):
            if line == 'This contents information':
                break
            if output:
                print(line)
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/TroubledMysteriousMonitors

Answer (score 1):

You could consider reading the entire text file into a string, and then using a regular expression to extract the contents you want:

```py
with open('test.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()

contents = re.search(r'^This contents information\n(.*?)\nThis contents information\b', inp, flags=re.M|re.S).group(1)
print(contents)
```

This prints:

```
City:LK
Country:LL
Postcode:123
```

Comment: Regex is so overkill for this, just use an if statement.

Comment: Regex isn't overkill at all, and should the OP's search requirements get more complex, your solution would become unwieldy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **split**, with `"This contents information"` as the delimiter. 
In the example above, the file will be split into 3 sections, of which we only need to grab the second one (index=1). You can then use `.strip()` to remove unwanted space.

#### Code:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as infile:
     text = infile.read()

required_info = text.split("This contents information")[1].strip()

print(required_info)
```

#### Output:

```
City:LK
Country: LL
Postcode:123
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of prewriting the line numbers, just have a conditional statement that checks for the data you want.

```
readText=open("test.txt","r")

with open('test.txt', 'r') as infile:
     for line in infile:
          line = line.strip()
          if line == "text to look for":
              printline = True
          elif line == "text to end content":
              printline = False
          elif printline == True:
              print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best method would be to use regex.

```
import re

text=""
with open('test.txt', 'r') as infile:
    text = infile.read()

# Don't forget to replace here with the word you want to search among what you want to find.

# This contents information(.*?)\nThis contents information

# this regex finds everything between these two words

# example: 'test 123asda test' -> test(.*?)test =>  ' 123asda '

regex = re.compile(r'This contents information(.*?)\nThis contents information', re.DOTALL)
matches = [m.groups()[0] for m in regex.finditer(text)]

for m in matches:
    print(f'{m.strip()}')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
with open("file.txt","r") as f: 
    data =f.readlines()
    string="".join(data) #join each line into one string
    ls=re.split(r"(\n*?)This contents information\n",string) #split the string where the regex we specified.
    for i in range(len(ls)): #print the list. Ohoo you got the answer
        print(ls[i])
```